# how to tell seekbar to start listen for setOnSeekBarChangeListener() in android?

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I have used four seekbars and placed one after another horizontally. Now if I start changing progress of first seekbar, the progress of first seekbar should change. And as soon as the first seekbar reaches at progress of 100, second seekbar should start change. The same flow applies for second and third seekbar also.

Is this possible ? Can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

here is a quick snippet, if i did understand your question correctly then the solution would be like below:

```
        SeekBar seekBar = new SeekBar(this);
        final SeekBar seekBar2 = new SeekBar(this);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (progress >= 100) seekBar2.setProgress(progress); // do the same for the other seekbars.
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
```

as soon as the first seekbar reaches 100, seekrBar2 will change its current progress following the first progress.
P.S this is a snippet code, you might need to follow it up and reflect your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A small change on Kosh's code :)

```
SeekBar seekBar1 = new SeekBar(this);
SeekBar seekBar2 = new SeekBar(this);
SeekBar seekBar3 = new SeekBar(this);

seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if (progress > 100) seekBar2.setProgress(progress-100); // do the same for the other seekbars.
    }
});

seekBar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if (progress > 100) seekBar3.setProgress(progress-100); // do the same for the other seekbars.
    }
});
```

This will help you :)